# Why would the Pricebook2Id standard field be on Contract in some orgs but not another?

Tags: custom-field, pricebook, contracts

Our QA and Production orgs have a `Pricebook2Id` standard field on `Contract` but our DEV org does not.

Field Service has been installed in our QA and Production orgs and not our DEV org, but looking at the "View Components", I don't see this field. Plus, any new fields added by Field Service would be custom fields (e.g. Pricebook_Id__c), right?

I discovered this discrepancy when I tried to deploy `Contract` page layouts from DEV (which doesn't have the field) to QA (which does have the field) and got this validation error:

```
Layout must contain an item for required layout field: Pricebook2Id
```

Anyone know why some of our orgs would have a `Pricebook2Id` standard field on `Contract` but not all?

Note, all of the orgs are on Summer '21.

Comment: What about Entitlements and Service Contracts? I'm not sure if that's related, but maybe?

Comment: How old is the dev org (i.e. when created?). Sometimes new standard fields don't always get propagated to sandboxes created under earlier versions. I've seen this happen with `Order`

Comment: We are not using Entitlements or Service Contracts. The sandbox was refreshed this year in April. I guess I'll open a case to understand the root cause, but we have deploy workarounds for now. Appreciate the suggestions.